# Need help with configurable product pricing (2 variable)

Tags: product, attributes, configurable-product, price

Somewhat new to Magento, and using it for a current business to create a web store.

I'm in need of help for how to create a configurable product with some specific pricing information that I cannot get right. Here is my best explanation of the situation (using an example product).

The product is being configured over two variables: Color (ish) and an optional addition I'll call LB [yes/no similar].

My issue is that the price differences are different for ALL variations of the item, as in they are not all comparable. The LB option is not the same price cost addition for each color option.

Example: M1900
M1900 Black..... no LB = 252.31, w/ LB = 312.58 [60.27 difference]
M1900 Galv...... no LB = 269.25, w/ LB = 330.52 [61.29 difference]
M1900 Red....... no LB = 260.82, w/ LB = 321.59 [60.77 difference]
ect...

Right now, when I create the Configurable Product, I'm setting the price to 0.00 (as you cannot buy a "base" M1900, it needs color / LB?). When created the associated child products, I start running into the issue with pricing. I'll use the example again. When creating the M1900 Black I set the color price to 252.31, and leave the other price off as there is no LB. When creating the M1900 Black LB the color price is already set, and I use the 60.27 difference as the yes LB price.

After creating this, however, the next LB item I create is using that 60.27 price which is not correct.

How do I go about setting individual prices for each combination... that will show up when configuring the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pricing scheme of `M1900` is not possible to perfectly achieve with Magento's configurable products. The closest pricing you can natively achieve with Magento is to create `M1900` as a configurable product with one configurable option `color`(-ish) and a custom yes-no option for `LB` on the configurable product itself.

With the above-suggested structure, you'll be able to achieve the desired pricing of the "color and no LB" set of products. If you fix the cost of adding `LB`, then it would make it perfect. However, it looks like this is not the case for you, so you may need to compromise on the cost of adding `LB`.

Alternatively, if you use an extension that allows configurable products to take on the price of the selected simple product, you can solve your issue. Check it out. I've never used it, so I don't know how well it works.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html